# Need assistance with awk/sed to identify/mark duplicate IP addresses

Tags: linux, awk, sed, ipv6, duplicate

Good day.

I have a text file which contains pod/node names and associated IPv6 addresses of which two pods have the same IP address, first pod **k8-worker0001c-cif-9d86d6dd4-vf9b9** and last pod **k8-worker0001c-ctdc-5bc95b699f-xnmrn**, the IP address being **2001:1890:e00f:3900::6**

```
k8-worker0001c-cif-9d86d6dd4-vf9b9
         2001:1890:e00f:3900::4/64 global nodad
         2001:1890:e00f:3900::6/64 global 

k8-worker0001c-cifpartner-64c89f8bc8-8p5pq
         2001:1890:e00f:3900::10/64 global 

k8-worker0001c-ctd-7d759784ff-2gk5d
         2001:1890:e00f:3900::a/64 global nodad
         2001:1890:e00f:3900::d/64 global 

k8-worker0001c-ctd-7d759784ff-hd8jp
         2001:1890:e00f:3900::c/64 global 

k8-worker0001c-ctd-7d759784ff-qkk4t
         2001:1890:e00f:3900::8/64 global nodad
         2001:1890:e00f:3900::f/64 global 

k8-worker0001c-ctd-7d759784ff-t6lwz
         2001:1890:e00f:3900::5/64 global 

k8-worker0001c-ctd-7d759784ff-vl8x9
         2001:1890:e00f:3900::9/64 global nodad
         2001:1890:e00f:3900::b/64 global 

k8-worker0001c-ctdc-5bc95b699f-xnmrn
         2001:1890:e00f:3900::7/64 global nodad
         2001:1890:e00f:3900::6/64 global
```

All I need is a one-liner to identify the duplicate IP address while retaining the rest, including the pod names.  I have tried using **awk** **!seen** but that deletes the duplicate which I don't want.

Therefore I'd like something like this:

```
k8-worker0001c-cif-9d86d6dd4-vf9b9
         2001:1890:e00f:3900::4/64 global nodad
         2001:1890:e00f:3900::6/64 global          DUPLICATE!

k8-worker0001c-cifpartner-64c89f8bc8-8p5pq
         2001:1890:e00f:3900::10/64 global 

k8-worker0001c-ctd-7d759784ff-2gk5d
         2001:1890:e00f:3900::a/64 global nodad
         2001:1890:e00f:3900::d/64 global 

k8-worker0001c-ctd-7d759784ff-hd8jp
         2001:1890:e00f:3900::c/64 global 

k8-worker0001c-ctd-7d759784ff-qkk4t
         2001:1890:e00f:3900::8/64 global nodad
         2001:1890:e00f:3900::f/64 global 

k8-worker0001c-ctd-7d759784ff-t6lwz
         2001:1890:e00f:3900::5/64 global 

k8-worker0001c-ctd-7d759784ff-vl8x9
         2001:1890:e00f:3900::9/64 global nodad
         2001:1890:e00f:3900::b/64 global 

k8-worker0001c-ctdc-5bc95b699f-xnmrn
         2001:1890:e00f:3900::7/64 global nodad
         2001:1890:e00f:3900::6/64 global         DUPLICATE!
```

Thanks in advance,
Bjoern

Comment: So there is only one address showing twice? Neither a third occurence nor another pair?

Comment: Hi Philippos.  Thus far I've only seen one address duplicated.

Answer (score 1):

A 2-pass approach using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ $ awk '{sub(/\r$/,"")} NR==FNR{cnt[$1]++; next} {print $0 (NF && cnt[$1]>1 ? "\tDUPLICATE!" : "")}' file file
k8-worker0001c-cif-9d86d6dd4-vf9b9
         2001:1890:e00f:3900::4/64 global nodad
         2001:1890:e00f:3900::6/64 global       DUPLICATE!

k8-worker0001c-cifpartner-64c89f8bc8-8p5pq
         2001:1890:e00f:3900::10/64 global

k8-worker0001c-ctd-7d759784ff-2gk5d
         2001:1890:e00f:3900::a/64 global nodad
         2001:1890:e00f:3900::d/64 global

k8-worker0001c-ctd-7d759784ff-hd8jp
         2001:1890:e00f:3900::c/64 global

k8-worker0001c-ctd-7d759784ff-qkk4t
         2001:1890:e00f:3900::8/64 global nodad
         2001:1890:e00f:3900::f/64 global

k8-worker0001c-ctd-7d759784ff-t6lwz
         2001:1890:e00f:3900::5/64 global

k8-worker0001c-ctd-7d759784ff-vl8x9
         2001:1890:e00f:3900::9/64 global nodad
         2001:1890:e00f:3900::b/64 global

k8-worker0001c-ctdc-5bc95b699f-xnmrn
         2001:1890:e00f:3900::7/64 global nodad
         2001:1890:e00f:3900::6/64 global       DUPLICATE!
```

That just assumes your pod names are unique.

Comment: Sorry Ed, 
`awk 'NR==FNR{cnt[$1]++; next} {print $0 (NF && cnt[$1]>1 ? "\tDUPLICATE!" : "")}' dup_ip.txt dup_ip.txt`
does not work.

Comment: As shown in my answer, the script I provided produces the output you provided from the input you provided so I'd need a bit more information than "does not work" to be able to help you further. Only saying something "does not work" is the worst possible problem statement in software and anything else in life.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's my version of awk (GNU Awk 4.0.2), but when I execute the commands as you listed, the output remains the same, without the 'DUPLICATE!'

Comment: So, taking a closer look, I noticed that awk actually replaced '2001' with 'DUPLICATE!'

`$ awk 'NR==FNR{cnt[$1]++; next} {print $0 (NF && cnt[$1]>1 ? "\tDUPLICATE!" : "")}' dup_ip.txt dup_ip.txt
k8-worker0001c-cif-9d86d6dd4-vf9b9
         2001:1890:e00f:3900::4/64 global nodad
        **DUPLICATE!**:e00f:3900::6/64 global 

k8-worker0001c-ctd-7d759784ff-qkk4t
         2001:1890:e00f:3900:8/64 global nodad
         2001:1890:e00f:3900:f/64 global 

k8-worker0001c-ctdc-5bc95b699f-xnmrn
         2001:1890:e00f:3900::7/64 global nodad
        **DUPLICATE!**:e00f:3900::6/64 global `

Comment: Based on [that comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/745310/need-assistance-with-awk-sed-to-identify-mark-duplicate-ip-addresses/745338?noredirect=1#comment1417621_745338), your input has DOS line endings so I just added `{sub(/\r$/,"")}` to my script to handle that for you but see [why-does-my-tool-output-overwrite-itself-and-how-do-i-fix-it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45772525/why-does-my-tool-output-overwrite-itself-and-how-do-i-fix-it) to understand what it is and other ways to fix it.

Comment: Thank you Ed.

It seems when you tee output to a file it adds the ^M DOS EOF, super annoying.  So what does the entire command line look like after you added `{sub(/\r$/,"")}`?

Comment: I believe I got it:  ` awk 'NR==FNR{cnt[$1]++; next} {sub(/\r$/,"")} {print $0 (NF && cnt[$1]>1 ? "\tDUPLICATE!" : "")}' `

Comment: As I said in my comment, I already edited the script in my answer to include that `sub()` statement but you can put the `sub()` in either place if there's always more than 1 field to be tested.

Answer (score 0):

##### Here a shot using a double `Perl`'s one-liner + `xargs`:

```
perl -MRegexp::Common -lnE '
    $h{$&}++ if /($RE{net}{IPv6})/;
    END{ print grep { $h{$_} > 1 } keys %h}
' file | xargs -I{} perl -spe 's/$ip.*/$&\t\tDUPLICATE!/g' -- -ip={} file
```

##### Output

```
k8-worker0001c-cif-9d86d6dd4-vf9b9
         2001:1890:e00f:3900::4/64 global nodad
         2001:1890:e00f:3900::6/64 global     DUPLICATE!

k8-worker0001c-cifpartner-64c89f8bc8-8p5pq
         2001:1890:e00f:3900::10/64 global 

k8-worker0001c-ctd-7d759784ff-2gk5d
         2001:1890:e00f:3900::a/64 global nodad
         2001:1890:e00f:3900::d/64 global 

k8-worker0001c-ctd-7d759784ff-hd8jp
         2001:1890:e00f:3900::c/64 global 

k8-worker0001c-ctd-7d759784ff-qkk4t
         2001:1890:e00f:3900::8/64 global nodad
         2001:1890:e00f:3900::f/64 global 

k8-worker0001c-ctd-7d759784ff-t6lwz
         2001:1890:e00f:3900::5/64 global 

k8-worker0001c-ctd-7d759784ff-vl8x9
         2001:1890:e00f:3900::9/64 global nodad
         2001:1890:e00f:3900::b/64 global 

k8-worker0001c-ctdc-5bc95b699f-xnmrn
         2001:1890:e00f:3900::7/64 global nodad
         2001:1890:e00f:3900::6/64 global    DUPLICATE!
```

##### Requirements

You need Perl's module [`Regexp::Common`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Regexp::Common)

You can install via:

```
cpan Regexp::Common
```

or via package manager:

```
apt install libregexp-common-perl
```

for Debian and derivatives

If you can't install system wide package, you can use [`perlbrew`](https://perlbrew.pl/) to install as regular user or simply download libs as regular user:

```
wget https://sputnick.fr/downloads/Regexp-Common.gz
tar xjvf Regexp-Common.gz
ls ./lib
```

then, you can use:

```
perl -I./lib -MRegexp::Common -lnE '
    $h{$&}++ if /($RE{net}{IPv6})/;
    END{ print grep { $h{$_} > 1 } keys %h}
' file | xargs -I{} perl -spe 's/$ip.*/$&    DUPLICATE!/g' -- -ip={} file
```

Comment: Thanks GIlles.
  As you anticipated, Can't locate Regexp/Common.pm.  Unfortunately, I can't install any packages on our system.

Comment: Which OS do you run?

Comment: CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core)

Comment: Check install instruction as regular user

Answer (score 0):

Here is a really simple Perl-based approach.  It assumes that the input stays stable, i.e. the lines that start with whitespace have the IP addresses in the first field after the whitespace.  It should work with a base Perl install, i.e. no modules required.

```
  perl -ne 's/\r//g; m/^\s+(\S+)\s+/ && $seen{$1}++; push @l, $_;
    END {$s=" "x7; foreach (@l) {m/^\s+(\S+)\s+/ && ($seen{$1}>1) && s/$/ $s DUPLICATE!/; print}}'
```

It produces output that is binary identical to your sample output.  :)

Comment: Thanks Morty.  I tried your command but get the same text that's in the file, whether I do cat the file and pipe it to perl or add the file to the end.

Comment: @Bjoern, it it possible that you have embedded carriage returns?  Try piping to "cat -vet", or remove the carriage returns.  I'll modify the Perl to remove any carriage returns.